# borderStyle not working in android - react-native

Tags: react-native

This still shows solid borderStyle.  After going through a lot i saw that in some cases using borderRadius shows the borderStyle. But still borderStyle 'dotted' and 'dashed' has no effects on it.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    style = {{ 
    borderStyle: 'dotted',
    borderWidth: 1
   }}
 >
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?I am also stuck at this.

Answer (score 15):

The borderStyle: 'dashed'/'dotted' should work if you add `borderRadius: 1` (Android only).

Also note that it works only with 'borderWidth' (not with 'borderBottomWidth' for example).

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 14):

Try this .
Its working for me.

```
style = {{ 
   flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderStyle: 'dotted',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 1,
    position: 'relative',
}}
```

Comment: @praj : did you install any node module for borderStyle?

Comment: @bittu Nothing added

Comment: how did your code work then?I have used your code,but nothing reflect in favour.

Comment: It worked for me. You must have the borderRadius:1 for some reason for it to work though.

Comment: @WaweruwaKamau that's the real answer here

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 5):

You have to add borderRadius to the style .

Comment: NOTE: As of writing, applying `borderStyle` to a single border edge is broken in React Native 0.63.2 but there is an open PR to fix this limitation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29099

Answer (score 4):

Adding borderRadius also worked for me.
use small values like below.
`borderRadius:0.1`

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the border style will not work if you didn't supply the (color, width, style, radius) proprieties altogether.

SOLUTION : include all of them :

```
example: {
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: "dashed",
    borderRadius: 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding borderRadius: 0.001px(zero doesnot work) ,
In that case it works.

Answer (score 1):

> you have to provide some borderRadius to make it work

```
borderRadius:5
```