# View Style Props in Android UI Components

Tags: android, react-native

Given an Android Native UI component called `MyNativeUIComponent` which extends a `LinearLayout`.

If I want to use [View Style Props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props) to set borders or padding, for example:

```
<MyNativeUIComponent
  style={{
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10,
    width: '100%'
  }}>

</MyNativeUIComponent>
```

Do I have to expose and implement `borderColor`, `borderWidth`, and `width` as a `@ReactProp` or `@ReactPropGroup` properties of MyNativeUIComponent as described [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android), or does React Native implement these standards properties because `MyNativeUIComponent` extends `LinearLayout` ?

Note that if I use styles as described above, it works on iOS but not in Android. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258084/borderstyle-not-working-in-android-react-native) and I tried different suggestions and none of them work.

Note 2: I am creating this question because after reading the documentation is not clear to me if I should expose and manually set every native component's property or not.

Comment: In android you can use  shadowOpacity, shadowOffset, shadowRadius property

Comment: So, are borderColor, borderWidth not supported on Android?

Comment: borderColor is supported

Comment: In native Android UI borderColor, borderWidth is not supported. If you want to add border to the any view (CardView, TextView etc...) you have to set drawable background. For example check this: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. use the below codes in your main xml, the `activity_main.xml`:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity"
       android:background="#dde4dd"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="vertical">
         <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/ border "
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. In the above code we have taken one text view with background as border so we need to create a file in drawable as `boarder.xml` and add the below codes:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
     <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
     <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
   </shape>
   ```
3. In the above code we have taken shape as root tag and given shape is rectangle and added width and padding for shape so add the below code to `src/MainActivity.java`:

   ```java
       package com.example.andy.myapplication;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import org.w3c.dom.Text;
   import java.util.Locale;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.text);
     textView.setText("Tutorialspoint india pvt ltd");
   }
   ```

Try to run you code and see the result.

Comment: This answer don't provide information about the questions I'm asking. The question is not about how to do something, but how does it work instead. Another thing I don't see in this answer is inherited properties, which is a central point of the question.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoAllende for your comment. apologize for bothering you, now, what should I do bro?

Comment: All good mate, you're not bothering me, in fact I appreciate the time you took to write the answer. Writing down my feedback is a chance for me to see if I'm wrong in my interpretation. I'm just looking for an answer and that's it. Have a nice day!