# BorderWidth react native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

i`m doing an app on expo, but when I put a borderWidth its only render on iOS but not on android, only render on the top of the view , this is the css, I hope you can help me

mainContainer:{
width:'100%',
height:'auto',
flex:1,
flexDirection:'row',
borderWidth:1,
borderColor:'#666666',
borderStyle:'solid'
},

[border not working on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgA3X.png)
[Code exaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCEhj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you want the border to apply to all sides like it is currently on IOS. If this is the case change borderBottomColor to borderColor:

```
mainContainer:{ width:'100%', height:'auto', flex:1, flexDirection:'row', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#666666', borderStyle:'solid' },
```

If this is not what you are asking please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but I already did it like you say and its the same, only renders on top

Comment: Have you tried removing border style? There are some issues relating to border style on android. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258084/borderstyle-not-working-in-android-react-native

Comment: It would help if I could see your code. Often times these issues occur because you are applying borders to a component that doesn't really work with border such as Text components. You can often solve this issue by wrapping your component in a View and applying the border styles there.

Comment: yes, I did it but its the same =( thanks for the help bro!

Comment: its actually a View container, let me edit the answer and I put a pic of my code

Comment: One thing I noticed is you are using the new Pressable API. I am not too familiar with Pressable's but perhaps the hit slop is messing with the border on android.  Also maybe the height: 'auto' is messing with the borders. height: 'auto' seems unnecessary here. Other than those things I am out of suggestions.

Comment: Thanks man, I follows all your instructions but same results, thanks anyway =)

Comment: I found the solution, I remove the flex and its works